# github pull-request with merging issues

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have a forked version B of the original repository A. There are "Issues" in A and B, the ones in B have been reported during testing of a new feature. How is it possible to include the issues of B into the repository A upon pull-request? I just made a simple test and the merged repository A does not include the issues from B. Is this impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least have some [cross-repository issue reference](https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets#cross-repository-issue-references)

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/447e39ab8d96b553cadc8d31799100190df230a8/68747470733a2f2f6769746875622d696d616765732e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f626c6f672f323031312f736563726574732f7265666572656e6365732e706e67]

> You can reference issues between repositories by mentioning user/repository#number in an issue. Once we see something like that — say, github/enterprise#59 — we'll make sure to update issue #59 in github's enterprise repository and let you know where it was referenced from

Beside that, there is no native way to integrate issues from one repo to the other: you would need to use a dedicated project like [`google/github-issue-mover`](https://github.com/google/github-issue-mover) for that.

[image: https://github.com/google/github-issue-mover/raw/master/README_assets/app.png]